# NGINX Server throws rewrite or internal redirection error

Tags: angular, ubuntu, nginx

I tried for the past few hours to serve my angular application on my ubuntu VM - but I just can't get it to work but I don't see the error.

here is what I did:
cloned the GitHub repo in root (so there is now one folder with my repo)
installed and built the angular App
installed nginx and wrote following config file:

```
server {
    listen 80; 
    server_name my ip address myDomain.de www.myDomain.de;
    root /LoL5v5Generator/dist;  
    index /index.html;
location / { 
    try_files $uri /index.html; 
  } 
}
```

I tried it also without the /lol/ in front of the index.html - didn't work aswell.
In the LoL5v5Generator inside the dist are the built assets directly so no sub-folder.
I get following error:

```
*1 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/index.html"
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Either the file `/LoL5v5Generator/dist/index.html` is missing or unreadable.